# Nexus 3 npm proxy failing most of the time

Tags: npm, nexus, nexus3

We're using Nexus 3.0.1-01 to proxy https://registry.npmjs.org/
We've configured a group containing the proxy to npmjs.org and our locally hosted npm repo. In the local npm-config we have pointed npm to our Nexus as registry.
**All** connections to the internet pass our corporate http(s) proxy.

When resolving "public" dependencies like bower (e.g. via `npm install -g bower`) with Nexus it will fail 8 out of 10 times. When we point to the official registry everything works fine 100% of the time.

The error looks like this:

```
$ npm install -g bower
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-107-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12

npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     npm-debug.log
```

Looking at the debug log, we get a HTTP 404 and then a HTTP 304 and then the install fails.

```
2 info using npm@2.14.12
3 info using node@v4.3.2
[...]
21 http request GET http://nexus/repository/npm/bower
22 http 404 http://nexus/repository/npm/bower
23 verbose headers { date: 'Thu, 02 Feb 2017 08:32:35 GMT',
23 verbose headers   server: 'Nexus/3.0.1-01 (OSS)',
23 verbose headers   'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
23 verbose headers   'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
23 verbose headers   'content-type': 'application/json',
23 verbose headers   'content-length': '37',
23 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'MISS from proxy',
23 verbose headers   'x-cache-lookup': 'HIT from proxy:3128',
23 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive' }
24 silly get cb [ 304, undefined ]
25 verbose get saving undefined to /user/.npm/nexus/repository/npm/bower/.cache.json
26 silly addNameTag next cb for bower with tag latest
27 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
27 verbose stack     at Function.keys (native)
27 verbose stack     at installTargetsError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:273:24)
27 verbose stack     at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:94:10)
27 verbose stack     at RES (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:23:14)
27 verbose stack     at f (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:17:25)
27 verbose stack     at fixName (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:29:5)
27 verbose stack     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/caching-client.js:173:7)
27 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:210:7
27 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Like I said, we can repeat the install a few times and eventually it will work. If we use https://registry.npmjs.org/ trough our proxy everything works fine.

We also have a Nexus 2.11.3-01 that also works just fine if we use this as npm registry (proxy).

I have searched the Sonatype JIRA but couldn't find any hints to whether this is a Nexus 3 issue or not.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: What version of npm/node and os are you using? Helpful for us to recreate the issue.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to the latest (3.2.0) and see if you have this issue?

Comment: I have done some further investigation. One problem is that npm for one won't access the registry every time. Another one is that npm obviously caches a "not found" result for quite some time...

After invalidating the cache each time I try to resolve, the problem still remains. Resolving works two times, then fails (404), then works two times, then fails...

We use npm 1.3.10. This version isn't aware of the no_proxy variable, so the resolving looks something like this:

npm => proxy => nexus => proxy => npmjs.org

I suspect the proxy as culprit here...

Comment: We use npm 1.3.10.  This is a very old version of npm.  Nexus will only work with npm 1.4 and higher.  I think the current version of npm is 4.1.2.

Comment: @DarthHater I have analysed the problem further now. It affects _all_ npm 2.x versions (we're using npm 2.14.12 with node 4.3.2) and also _all_ Nexus 3.x versions. I have tested against Nexus 2.x and Artifactory 5. Both do work just fine. Our internal proxy is a Squid I guess, I'm trying to get a configuration from IT.

Comment: By the way, it only affects group repositories. If I just use a simple proxy repo (pointing to registry.npmjs.org) it will work too. Using a group will break things, even if there's only the (working) proxy in that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, together with IT I was able to solve this.

Turns out it was a weird bug in Squid. After some changes in the caching configuration resolving now works as expected.

Thanks everyone involved for contributing!